# Subtract hours from date object in bash

Tags: bash, date

I need to find a time X hours before the previous midnight, thus I would like to subtract X hours from a date object.

**Example**

```
# Finding the previous midnight
date -d "yesterday 23:59:59"
Mon Jul 11 00:00:00 CEST 2022
```

**What I want**
I would like to find the date X hours before this midnight

```
x=4
Mon Jul 10 20:00:00 CEST 2022
```

Comment: `20:00:00` isn't midnight; is it on purpose? If so, what midnight would it be? `Jul 10 00:00:00` or `Jul 10 24:00:00`?

Comment: True, I will fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems one can just write the following:

```
date --date 'yesterday 23:59:59 CEST -4 hours'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this `date` command:

```bash
date -d "today 0 -4 hours"
```

Here:

- `today 0`: gets midnight date-time for today's date
- `-4 hours`: subtracts 4 hours from midnight time